com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message and Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
Im working on a springboot project with mongdb database. in Config files, I have only SecurityConfig file.
This is the error I got . And I have no idea how to fix this.

com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateReadException(InternalStreamConnection.java:705) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessageWithAdditionalTimeout(InternalStreamConnection.java:583) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:428) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receive(InternalStreamConnection.java:381) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:221) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:153) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:278) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:345) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:794) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:1025) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:483) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:477) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1461) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1066) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:176) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:196) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:716) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessageWithAdditionalTimeout(InternalStreamConnection.java:580) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    ... 5 common frames omitted

I have tried setting these in application.properties. It didnt work.
spring.data.mongodb.connect-timeout=10000         # Connection timeout in milliseconds
spring.data.mongodb.socket-timeout=60000          # Socket read timeout in milliseconds
spring.data.mongodb.connection-timeout=10000      # Connection establishment timeout in milliseconds
spring.data.mongodb.server-selection-timeout=30000 # Server selection timeout in milliseconds
spring.data.mongodb.max-wait-time=120000          # Max wait time in milliseconds for a connection from the pool

